# IISExpress not starting

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, episerver

I have an EPIserver site that wont start when i run it in IISExpress, but when i run it in the VS Development Server it works.

Im not getting any error message when trying to make it go with IIS Express, it just starts and never presents any error message or the website. I dont even get a timeout, just a blank page waiting....

When i debug and hit Break All i get this code:

```
private void LoadPressItems()
        {
            var startPage = GetPage(PageReference.StartPage);
            if (startPage[Globals.PressItemRootPropertyString] != null)
            {
                var pressItemRoot = startPage[Globals.PressItemRootPropertyString] as PageReference;
                if (!PageReference.IsNullOrEmpty(pressItemRoot))
                {
                    if (MaxItems <= 0) MaxItems = 5;
                    var pages = (from page in GetChildren(pressItemRoot)
                                 where page.IsPublished() &&
                                 page.StopPublish > DateTime.Now
                                 select page).Take(MaxItems).ToList();
                    pageList.DataSource = pages;
                    pageList.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to add code because [SO is for programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). SO expects you to [try](http://whathaveyoutried.com) first and post specific questions when you get stuck (with a programming question). You should try vendor support, community or maybe [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis) - it sounds like a setup matter more than a programming issue.

Comment: If you start the application with debugging, then hit the "break all" button, where does the application break. What does the call stack show you?

Comment: @GregB Good question! Thanks. I answer below these comments.

Comment: Or actually, i updated the question.

Comment: @Lautaro What line does the debugger say it is stopped at?

Answer (score 0):

I rarely  use IIS Express, but my suggestion would be to make sure that EPiServerFramework.config is writable.

If that won't solve the problem, configure log4net (EPiServerLog.config) and put it to debug or info-mode, and you'll probably get a clearer picture were the site fails.

I could also recommend using http://world.episerver.com for EPiServer-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

- IIS Express = IIS7
- VS Development Server = IIS6

You need two different Web.config files unless you really want to puzzle and make one that works on both IIS versions...

I recommend you pick the local server matching the live environment IIS version and go from there.